# How to create QR Code for Android app?

Tags: android, qr-code

I'm going to develop mobile app that using QR Code to make easy for the user to view the information detail of the item. Anyone have reference to help me to create QR Code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the [Zxing library](https://github.com/zxing/zxing), it is an open-source, multi-format 1D/2D barcode image processing library implemented in Java and it supports QR Code.

There are [very good tutorials](http://khurramitdeveloper.blogspot.com.ar/p/android-barcode-scan-using-zxing-library.html) explaining how to create apps to read QR codes from scratch using Zxing library.

Comment: By the way do you know some references about how to make android apps (Eclipse Plugin perhaps?) that read QR code. Just sayin'

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Zbar](https://github.com/ZBar/ZBar/tree/master/android) or [ZXing](https://code.google.com/p/zxing/). For ZXing tutorial is [Here](http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/09/android-generate-qr-code-using-zxing.html)